# Error "param is missing or the value is empty: personas_x_tipos_persona"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm starting in rails and I have this error that I'm not able to solve..

> Error - param is missing or the value is empty:
>   personas_x_tipos_persona

Controller

```
class PersonasController < ApplicationController
  def create_cliente
    @cliente = Persona.new(persona_params)
    @personas_x_tipos_personas = Persona.new(tipos_personas_params)
    if @cliente.save
      redirect_to show_clientes_path
    else
      render :new_cliente
    end
  end
  private
  def persona_params
    params.require(:persona).permit(:nombre, :apellido, :direccion, :ruc, :contacto, :email)
  end
  def tipos_personas_params
    params.require(:personas_x_tipos_persona).permit(:linea_credito)
  end
end
```

view

```
<div>
  <%= form_for :persona ,:url => add_cliente_path, :html => {:method => :post} do |f|%>
    <% @cliente.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" margin-top:10px">
        * <%=message%>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.text_field :nombre, placeholder: "Nombre del Cliente"%>
    <%= f.text_field :apellido, placeholder: "Apellido del Cliente"%>
    <%= f.text_field :direccion, placeholder: "Direccion del Cliente"%>
    <%= f.text_field :ruc, placeholder: "RUC del Cliente"%>
    <%= f.text_field :contacto, placeholder: "Contacto del Cliente"%>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email del Cliente""%>

      <%= f.fields_for :personas_x_tipos_persona do |pxp|%>
        <%= pxp.number_field :linea_credito, placeholder: "Linea de Credito del Cliente"%>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar'%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> param is missing or the value is empty: personas_x_tipos_persona

The problem is with this line `@personas_x_tipos_personas = Persona.new(tipos_personas_params)`(*actually this is not needed*) which is calling `tipos_personas_params`.

From the docs of [**require(key)**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require),

> When passed a single key, if it exists and its associated value is
>   either present or the singleton false, returns said value
>
> Otherwise raises ActionController::ParameterMissing

So, in your case the `require` is expecting `:personas_x_tipos_persona`, while this is missing in the `params`, so is the error.

Actually, the ***form object*** is `:persona` not `:personas_x_tipos_persona`. Also as I can see that you are using `fields_for`, so you need to whitelist `:personas_x_tipos_persona_attributes` inside `persona_params` and the `tipos_personas_params` method is not needed. The below code should get you going.

```
class PersonasController < ApplicationController
  def create_cliente
    @cliente = Persona.new(persona_params)
    #this is not needed
    #@personas_x_tipos_personas = Persona.new(tipos_personas_params) 
    if @cliente.save
      redirect_to show_clientes_path
    else
      render :new_cliente
    end
  end

  private
  def persona_params
    params.require(:persona).permit(:nombre, :apellido, :direccion, :ruc, :contacto, :email, personas_x_tipos_persona_attributes: [:id, :linea_credito])
  end
end
```

Comment: When I add in **persona**(nombre,apellido, etc.) I also want to add in **personas_x_tipos_personas **(id_persona,id_tipos_persona,linea_credito,saldo) 
I think I should do something like this, but I pulled that mistake

`def create_cliente
    @cliente = Persona.new(persona_params)
    @personas_x_tipos_personas = PersonasXTiposPersona.new(Persona.last.id,
    TiposPersona.find_by(:descripcion => 'Cliente'),tipos_personas_params,saldo:0)
    if @cliente.save
      redirect_to show_clientes_path
    else
      render :new_cliente
    end
  end`